# Joining dataframes in R (1:n relation)

Tags: r, dataframe, join, tidyverse

I have a data.frame `df1`

```
df1 <- data.frame(id=1:10)
```

and I have a second data.frame `df2`

```
df2 <- data.frame(id=1:100, key=sample(1:10,100,replace=T), var1=sample(c(TRUE, FALSE),100, replace=T), var2=sample(c("X", "Y"),100, replace=T))
```

Variable `df2$key` is a secondary key and points to the variable `df1$id`.

Now for each entry in `df1` I would like to check how many entries there are in `df2`, given a certain condition.

An example:
If `df1$id==5` I would like to create a variable `df1$count` that counts the number of entries in data.frame `df2` where `df2$key==5` and `df2$var==TRUE`.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you could do it in base R:

```
merge(df1, aggregate(var1 ~ key, df2, FUN = sum), 
      by.x = "id", by.y = "key", all.x = TRUE)
   id var1
1   1    3
2   2    1
3   3    4
4   4    6
5   5    9
6   6    4
7   7    5
8   8    7
9   9    4
10 10    3
```

or using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

df2 %>% 
  filter(var1) %>% 
  count(key) %>% 
  right_join(df1, by = c("key" = "id"))
```

In both cases we do the counting first and then merge the result to df1.